# Pointing localhost to domain name gives error

Tags: url, iis, dns, localhost

I want my local host to point to a domain name so that I can test the Yahoo API because it doesn't accept localhost:port as the callback domain.

I have done following changes to the host file

127.0.0.1 www.srsrtest.com

But when I try to open the domain name site, it gives 403 forbidden error.

[Forbideen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyoQh.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The # in the beginning means it’s commented out

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thanks for it, but now i am getting 403 forbidden error, i have edited the question and you can see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP error 403.14 means no default document is configured https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/942062/http-error-403-14-forbidden-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage

You need to install the Default Document feature into IIS and try again.